# How do I add a skip condition to a for loop without slowing it down?

Tags: python, performance

I am writing a function which processes a big list of elements, and want to add the functionality that certain elements are skipped depending on an input argument. Here's what the code looks like:

```py
def f(lst, skipsEnabled=False):
    for elem in lst:
        if skipsEnabled and skipCheck(elem):
            continue
        else:
            # do stuff to elem here
```

When skipsEnabled is false, the `if skipsEnabled` conditional can be ignored every time, however it still gets checked on every iteration and it slows my loop down. I could put the conditional before the loop, but then I'd need to duplicate the loop and this is not very OOPy since all the `elem` processing code would be copy-pasted in both loops.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: *"and it slows my loop down"* - please prove that claim. Have you done any actual performance measurements? And if so: how did you perform those? What were the results?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, I did some timing checks. Though not compact, the elem processing code runs quickly, and this check adds ~2% to the run time

Comment: Yes, I do. Prove it, show how you actually performed that test, on how much data, what is the runtime of the overall application (is the 2% based on seconds or nanoseconds), why does this matter in the first place? This overall sounds like very premature optimization and highly doubt the rest of your code is so performant that this matters at all. Why even use python if your 2% runtime difference is that important?

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions about what I am writing without knowing a single thing about it

Comment: I know that basically all questions about performance on SO are ill-suited because they never actually correctly measured any performance nor do they have a way to verify any answer actually improved the performance. And given how reluctant you are about it I would say this is in the same ballpark. I did my work, asked for clarification and (close and down) voted, moving on.

Comment: @AndyK You're leaving a lot to be assumed because you've provided the bare minimum amount of information. *"it slows my loop down"* is **very** open to interpretation without any examples.

Comment: You accepted Tim's answer, but is that actually faster for you? That seems doubtful, especially with my benchmark results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a method to do the element processing code and then have the loop with or without the conditional and then call the same method for the processing.

It is highly unlikely that you are actually generating a large efficiency saving here, though. The `skipsEnabled and skipCheck(elem)` will short circuit and never call `skipCheck()` so it's a single boolean check that always branches the same way. That will optimise well.

Comment: Please demonstrate that this makes it faster. I rather suspect it makes it *slower*.

Comment: I posted a benchmark now, this was indeed slower than the original. Or at least the code as I imagined it was. Let me know if I did it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark with 100,000 elements, every second getting skipped if skipping is enabled:

```
skipsEnabled = True
  9.82 ± 0.29 ms  Kelly
 14.50 ± 0.18 ms  original
 19.48 ± 0.72 ms  B_Remmelzwaal
 19.62 ± 0.41 ms  Tim

skipsEnabled = False
  1.52 ± 0.03 ms  Kelly
  1.54 ± 0.02 ms  B_Remmelzwaal
  2.16 ± 0.02 ms  original
  8.59 ± 0.29 ms  Tim
```

The fastest is a variation of B Remmelzwaal's, but using `itertools.filterfalse`:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def f(lst, skipsEnabled=False):
    if skipsEnabled:
        lst = filterfalse(skipCheck, lst)
    for elem in lst:
        elem
```

Tim's is how I imagine they meant it, as they provided no code.

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVTNjtMwED5xyVPMBTWuQsUWilCkXEBw4Yb2VlWR24x3rdpOZDuwpeqTcNkL3HkFHmOfBv8kTbPLdjngm8ffzHzfzHi-_2x29rpWt7c_WstevL17VjBdS7BcIrfAZVNr292S8MItalvXwvSPjAtnYlQYjAhjqeXG8s0RIpGqzNkr_JIkFTKoNb_iiopUGOsetrwxHxRdC6yKjz4QyRNwh9UaUKBLqsAho9EfzkZOQFUVDO-vcbNNvQsZwP5samW5avFoRJdlDPFekd0ll08Q86hG1xs05n62EOYvHAfEo6o6L1Xb82L8GWVPHio6m2TsHDS_Kz-jlCi-faVPtuVRZc4Nim4gUkHluqJwk98TdEMyDyTnOzx04xMKsfsfjMKIpkci_86CtcrNcnGc2sxPSDYuWRZ5RsqDWNUR1GhbrUDBc5gnSWS1vNQtZhB0rGAKFy-n00X3JtwHSjVVV5gGM3Ft8ixHU-_YnoTwiRrNlU3ZZD_CFXCYOH8I_9gL2bMclqsgm_koQeAhiXPtv69JWUfcevzSenr4KnhY72Hct8YqDQGXbEWW-WK1OlXqOPhfn1pD8jezOTvA71-wDysg2F4HmzQw8cR83NLHjZLni5MFMDDs--ILFFdSN2Q5sIcD4sZMtXKNurggvWNHd0abBpWjT_rk7ERUyJXBFndFqEXHJda2r04GbFaWikosS3KsPIlbtFum_VL9Aw)):

```py
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import filterfalse
from statistics import mean, stdev

def original(lst, skipsEnabled=False):
    for elem in lst:
        if skipsEnabled and skipCheck(elem):
            continue
        else:
            elem

def Tim(lst, skipsEnabled=False):
    def process(elem):
        elem
    if skipsEnabled:
        for elem in lst:
            if not skipCheck(elem):
                process(elem)
    else:
        for elem in lst:
            process(elem)

def B_Remmelzwaal(lst, skipsEnabled=False):
    if skipsEnabled:
        lst = filter(lambda x: not skipCheck(x), lst)
    for elem in lst:
        elem

def Kelly(lst, skipsEnabled=False):
    if skipsEnabled:
        lst = filterfalse(skipCheck, lst)
    for elem in lst:
        elem

funcs = original, Tim, B_Remmelzwaal, Kelly

def skipCheck(n):
    return n % 2

lst = [True, False] * 10**5
lst = list(range(10**5))

for skipsEnabled in True, False:
  print(f'{skipsEnabled = }')

  times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
  def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '

  for _ in range(25):
    for f in funcs:
      t = timeit(lambda: f(lst, skipsEnabled), number=1)
      times[f].append(t)

  for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
  print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filterfalse()` from itertools to filter out any elements which don't satisfy the condition, and loop over those:

```py
from itertools import filterfalse

def f(lst, skipsEnabled=False):
    if skipsEnabled:
        lst = filterfalse(skipCheck, lst)
    for elem in lst:
        # do stuff to elem here
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the `filter` result to a list. You can iterate the filter object itself.

Comment: Oh right, you can add the `skipsEnabled` in the filter too. I'll update it right away.

Comment: In what way does that change anything in terms of runtime?

Comment: It doesn't, nor does what OP initially stated, but I guess this would be a "cleaner way to do it", as asked in the last sentence.

Comment: I would argue this is way less clean (opinion based) and does not solve the question from the title. (further proving that it is a bad idea to ask multiple questions in the same post)

Comment: I would have to agree. I mean, guess I tried right? Feel like the only cleaning up that could be done would be removing the useless `else:`.

Comment: In the first version you had `lst` being either the filtered items or the original list. That made more sense as an alternative approach.

Comment: @khelwood I see I misinterpreted your first comment. I think it'd be best to revert it to that. It doesn't make sense to filter when `skipsEnabled` isn't even True haha.

Comment: If skips are disabled, this is faster, but if they're enabled, I rather suspect it's slower. But if you used `filterfalse`, it might be faster. A benchmark with both cases would be good.

Comment: @KellyBundy Didn't know about `filterfalse`, was kind of what I was looking for.

Comment: Wrote a benchmark myself now, results as predicted.